# cgi-script script not found or unable to stat xampp

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, xampp, cgi

I have a cgi script in the cgi-bin of my htdocs directory that gives the "script not found or unable to stat" message on the Apache error log. I have other cgi scripts in the same directory that work fine. I have checked the permissions and they are exactly the same. What can the problem be?

Comment: Maybe there is an error in the cgi script itself

Comment: @andrea It is a standard commercial script from HotCgiScripts for a thing called EasyFileManager. The first line had to be altered to locate the perl module. The line is '#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"'. That is the same as in the scripts that work.